# flickrapi (js) multiple async calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I allmost banged my head into the wall because I can't get the following code too work. I'm trying to code a photo gallery with the flickrApi and have problems with multiple async calls. But perhaps there is a cleaner solution to code this.

openPhotoset() is called when clicking the link of a photoset. Unfortunately getting the description of a photo I need to use a different method, which means another async call. I'm looping through the data, but because I make the call in a loop (that's when I have the photo-id available) the deferred of openPhotoset() doesn't resolve after looping but before. I read and have seen examples of $.when() used in a loop, filling an array with deferreds and checking with $.when but I seem to fail horribly at it. Is this the solution I need or is there another road to salvation? ;)

I want to execute different functions after all calls within openPhotoset() has completed.

```
        function openPhotoset(photosetId) {
            var currentPhotoset = [],
                deferred = $.Deferred();

            _requestPhotosOfSet(photosetId).done(function(data){
                $(data.photoset.photo).each(function(i, photo){
                    var objPhoto = {};

                    objPhoto.id = photo.id;
                    objPhoto.title = photo.title;
                    objPhoto.farm = photo.farm;
                    objPhoto.server = photo.server;
                    objPhoto.secret = photo.secret;

                    // get photo description
                    requestPhotoInfo(photo.id).done(function(data) {

                        objPhoto.description =  data.photo.description._content;
                        currentPhotoset.push(objPhoto);

                    }).then(function() {
                        // TODO: renders with each iteration, shouldnt!
                        var template = $('#li-gallery').html(),
                            result = Mustache.render(template, {currentPhotoset:currentPhotoset});

                        showGallery();
                        _$fyGallery.find('.gallery-list').html(result);

                        deferred.resolve();

                    });
                });

            });

            return deferred;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing `.done()` for `.then()` in a couple of places, and rearranging things a bit - well quite
 a lot.

I think you've probably been searching for something like this :

```
function openPhotoset(photosetId) {
    return _requestPhotosOfSet(photosetId).then(function(data) {
        var promises = $(data.photoset.photo).map(function(photo) {
            return requestPhotoInfo(photo.id).then(function(data) {
                return {
                    id: photo.id,
                    title: photo.title,
                    farm: photo.farm,
                    server: photo.server,
                    secret: photo.secret,
                    description: data.photo.description._content
                };
            });
        }).get();//.get() is necessary to convert a jQuery object to a regular js array.
        return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
            var template = $('#li-gallery').html(),
                result = Mustache.render(template, {
                    currentPhotoset: Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
                });
            showGallery();
            _$fyGallery.find('.gallery-list').html(result);
        });
    });
}
```

The main difference here is the creation of an array of promises as opposed to an array of photo objects, and allowing the promises to convey the data. This allows `$.when()` to fire off a callback when all the promises are fulfilled - ie when data objects have been composed for all photos in the set.

Note the use of `.map()` instead of `.each()`, thus simplifying the creation of `promises`.

And finally, the overall promise returned by `openPhotoset()` allows whatever action to be taken on completion of the whole process. Just chain `.then()`.

```
openPhotoset(...).then(function() {
    // here, do whatever
});
```

---

**EDIT**

The overall pattern is probably easier to understand if the inner workings are pulled out and rephrased as named promise-returning functions - `getPhotoInfoObject()` and `renderData()`.

```
function openPhotoset(photosetId) {
    function getPhotoInfoObject(photo) {
        return requestPhotoInfo(photo.id).then(function(data) {
            //$.extend() is much less verbose than copying `photo`'s properties into a new object longhand.
            return $.extend(photo, {description: data.photo.description._content});
        });
    }
    function renderData() {
        var template = $('#li-gallery').html(),
            currentPhotoset = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments),
            result = Mustache.render(template, {
                currentPhotoset: currentPhotoset
            });
        showGallery();
        _$fyGallery.find('.gallery-list').html(result);
    }
    // With the inner workings pulled out as getPhotoInfoObject() and renderData(),
    // the residual pattern is very concise and easier to understand.
    return _requestPhotosOfSet(photosetId).then(function(data) {
        var promises = $(data.photoset.photo).map(getPhotoInfoObject).get();
        return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(renderData);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Roamer-1888 I was indeed looking for this. Thanks for showing me a different way to approach this as well. I still find it hard to understand the $.when.apply(null, promises) as I'm not sure what .apply(null, promises) is needed for. My guess is an array of promises which $.when can loop through and return 1 'master' promise? Also, why the null as parameter? I've read into apply (javascriptissexy.com but can't seem to figure it out..)

Comment: Flowen, `.apply()` `.call()` and `.bind()` are related js Function methods. All three take a "context" as their first parameter - ie an object that will be used as `this` within the target function. If the target function has no `this` (in its immediate scope), then a context is not required but the first parameter slot must still be occupied - so you can pass 'null'. jQuery's `$.when()` has a weakness in that it only accepts regular, comma-separated parameters, whereas in many cases we would like to pass an array. By executing `$.when.apply(null, array)`, we overcome this limitation.

Comment: I have added a section to try to explain the pattern used in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was so blinded by the defereds and $.when function that I didn't notice all I needed was to create a counter and  count down each time requestPhotoInfo was done and after render the html